# How to use Capistrano with Rails and Docker-compose?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, capistrano3

I'm deploying a Rails Application with Capistrano.
It doesn't have any problem in normally way with Nginx and Passenger.

Now, I move to use docker-compose.

**Capfile**

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

**deploy.rb**

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "docker compose task"
  task docker_compose: :updated do
    on roles(:web, :app), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      within release_path do
        execute "cd #{release_path} && docker-compose up --build -d"
      end
    end
  end
  after 'deploy:updated', 'deploy:docker_compose'
end
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=myapp12345

  redis:
    image: 'redis:3.2-alpine'
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/var/lib/redis/data'

  website:
    depends_on:
      - 'redis'
      - 'db'
    build: .
    image: namle/myapp_api
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/myapp_ruby'
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis
    env_file:
      - '.env'

  sidekiq:
    depends_on:
      - 'redis'
      - 'db'
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis
    volumes:
      - '.:/myapp_ruby'
    env_file:
      - '.env'

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

volumes:
  redis:
  website:
  sidekiq:
  nginx-proxy:
```

It runs OKAY.

**But I have PROBLEM**

Docker-compose will create new network groups, volumes, images, containers after deploy **because of `release_path` changed**.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to `docker-compose cli` [Compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/):

```
Define and run multi-container applications with Docker.

Usage:
  docker-compose [-f=<arg>...] [options] [COMMAND] [ARGS...]
  docker-compose -h|--help

Options:
  -f, --file FILE             Specify an alternate compose file (default: docker-compose.yml)
  -p, --project-name NAME     Specify an alternate project name (default: directory name)
  ...
```

use `-p` flag to ensure project-name doesn't change when directory name changes and networks are not recreated

EDIT: Assuming this is a non-prod env and you don't expect to mount code in prod containers or run this setup for prod...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Capistrano with Docker. Capistrano is designed to repeatedly deploy an application to an existing server, while Docker is designed to bundle up an application into a container which is deployed.

I don't personally use Docker, so I can't give you instructions, but in a nutshell, you add a Dockerfile to your project, run `docker build` (or something like that), and then deploy the resulting container to your server.

Docker Compose (if I understand it correctly) is a way of assembling a set of existing containers. So you need to already have your application container created before Docker Compose will run that and other containers to create your server environment.

Comment: Thanks for your information.
Docker-compose can help you run a Dockerfile and generate container.
Docker and Capistrano have difference purpose. 
If I can configure docker-compose to update the same container when running it in many folders, It'll OKAY.